# Regex, match 3 groups, second and third might be optional

Tags: javascript, regex

Given I have a string: `Sebastian New York Canal st : Dinner at 5 c'clock.`
Where:

- **Sebastian** is first match
- **New York Canal st** second (might be many spaces and dots)
- **Dinner at 5 c'clock.** third (might be many spaces and dots)

between 2nd and 3rd group I have colon to separate those groups.

I wrote regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/iI6kN8/1

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)?([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)?(:\ ([A-Za-z0-9'. ]+))
```

And it works when I have 3 groups:

[image]
[image]

but when I have:

- `Sebastian New York Canal st`

or

- `Sebastian`

Does not

Comment: Maybe [`/([A-Za-z0-9]+)([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)?(: ([A-Za-z0-9'. ]+))?/`](https://regex101.com/r/uC3pO6/1) is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 3rd group optional:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)?([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)?(:\ ([A-Za-z0-9'. ]+))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/zW1oM6/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
/^(\w+)(?:(.+?(?=:|$))\:?(.*)?)/m
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iI6kN8/3)